# Separating images from one multiple exposure image on Nikon camera

Tags: nikon, software, raw, exposure

By mistake, I have images that have dual exposures superimposed in Nikon RAW format.  These exposures were 2 seconds apart, so, it needs to be separated.  Is there any way to separate these exposures in two images using Capture NX2 or similar software?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How can multiple exposures be in the same RAW file? As far as I know a RAW file has one set of pixel data and sometimes the resulting JPG image. One set of data per each pixel, therefore no way to split them.

Comment: @OlafM: it sounds like OP accidentally used the "Multiple Exposure" setting in camera. It will indeed take multiple shots on the same "frame".

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no practical way of deducing one of images from "multiexposure" serie which results in single file.