# Can I extract photo from multi exposure photo from a Pentax K-70?

Tags: photo-editing, pentax, multiple-exposure

I accidentally selected the *multi exposure mode* on my Pentax K-70, so all my photos are overlapping.

Is there a way to extract the original photos?

Comment: You may want to specify the camera model. No real hope to recover the shots, though.

Comment: Edit your question to add that information

Comment: @xenoid - you could undelete the answer, keep that part for info & just slap an opening para "If you did this, you can't un-bake a cake. Here's how to fix it for next time" ;)

Comment: similar: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/71109/separating-images-from-one-multiple-exposure-image-on-nikon-camera

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible to separate the input images. The camera saves the exposures in memory and combines them to create the image file. It does not save a file for each exposure.

Comment: Damn ! No ..... :<

Comment: @DavidJawHpan The future is filled with more good pictures. And mistakes.

Comment: Thanks ! I will